# What are the current theories on the formation of satellite tornados

Tags: meteorology, wind, storms, thunderstorm, tornado

I have already searched the web for information on the formation of [satellite tornadoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_tornado) but all the sites say the mechanism is unknown.

What are the current leading theories for their formation?

Comment: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=07b0e1205ac848baa2f67f28214aac92002b7e5c